# Python Adventure Game -> Chose A or B in a while loop not working!

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to create a simple adventure game in Python. I've come to a point where I need to ask the user if they wish to choose option A or B and am using a while loop to try and do this:

```
AB = input("A or B?")

while AB != "A" or "a" or "B" or "b":
    input("Choose either A or B")

if AB == "A" or "a":
    print("A")
elif AB == "B" or "b":
    print("B")
```

The thing is, no matter what you input, the question "Choose either A or B" comes up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code?  Right now that's just invalid code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `while` statement is evaluating on the conditionals `or`, which is always true for the strings you provided.

```
while AB != "A" or "a" or "B" or "b":
```

means:

```
while (AB != "A") or "a" or "B" or "b":
```

Non-empty strings are always True, so writing `or "B"` will always be true, and will always ask for input. Better to write:

```
while AB.lower() not in ('a','b'):
```

Answer (score 3):

`AB != "A" or "a" or "B" or "b"`
should be
`AB.upper() not in ('A','B')`

Answer (score 2):

```
AB != "A" or "a" or "B" or "b"
```

is interpreted as

```
(AB != "A") or ("a") or ("B") or ("b")
```

and since `"a"` is always `true`, the result of this check will always be `true`.

Comment: `/and since "A"/and since "a"/`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use:

```
AB = raw_input("A or B?").upper()
```

and then the `not in` construct as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `raw_input()` function, instead, like this:

```
ab = raw_input('Choose either A or B > ')
while ab.lower() not in ('a', 'b'):
    ab = raw_input('Choose either A or B > ')
```

`input()` expects a Python expression as input; according to the Python documentation, it is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. Just use `raw_input()`, along with the other suggestions posted here.

Comment: It looks like he's using Python 3, in which case input() is actually what he needs to use, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    inp = raw_input    # Python 2.x
except NameError:
    inp = input        # Python 3.x

def chooseOneOf(msg, options, prompt=': '):
    if prompt:
        msg += prompt
    options = set([str(opt).lower() for opt in options])
    while True:
        i = inp(msg).strip().lower()
        if i in options:
            return i

ab = chooseOneOf('Choose either A or B', "ab")

lr = chooseOneOf('Left or right', ('left','right'))
```